# Associating public IP in Azure

Tags: azure

I think I'm going crazy. I am trying to associate a public IP with my VM in Azure. I have done this before, but now something seems wrong. I associate the IP and the change does not stick for some reason? Maybe I am just missing something. I took a little video to show my steps.
http://d.pr/i/pyBE

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Cheers
Dan

Comment: oh! hmmmm looks like the video cut off. Sorry guys... however yes I have gone through all the steps, I enable the public IP.. save it.... then when I got back.. its disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am telling you things your already know, but (at least on my laptop), your video doesn't show the last steps of your configuration of your networkinterface web001182.

Are you doing the following actions :

- Go into Settings
- Then Click on IP addresses
- Then Enabled Public IP address
- Then configure require settings with your existing NewIPApril26.

Hope this helps

Best regards

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes those are the steps I have followed.
However the IP never binds. Here are some screenshots:
I enable and hit save: http://prntscr.com/axdrg9
I then navigate away and go back and: http://prntscr.com/axdrtx

Comment: Are you trying to use a static public IP address ? If yes it seems that you have to disassociate the IP from the network interface, make the IP static and then reassociate the IP in your network interface. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885977/setting-static-ip-on-azure-vm-via-portal-ui/36886465#36886465

Comment: Thanks again for helping, but I have tried this, and still the same results. Here is a quick video of what I did... then at the end after clicking save, it does not bind. http://d.pr/i/1f8Tb

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of digging, it seems I needed to fix it via the Azure cli. I needed to associate the public IP that was already created to the Network Interface.

The command was:
azure network nic set -g myresourcegroup -p mypublicipname mynicname

It seems my GUI portal is broken, because even my Network Security Groups needed to be edited via CLI. I have notified Azure.

azure network nsg rule create -p TCP -u 80
azure network nsg rule create -p TCP -u 443

I hope this helps someone.
Dan

Comment: Hi,You were right. There was an issue on the portal. It has been now fixed. Usage of Azure Cli is no more a requirement for this feature. Best regards. Stephane