# Setting static IP on azure vm via Portal UI

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm having a really weird situation. I'm trying to set the IP for a network interface attached to a VM to static via the UI. I hit the static button, whack in a valid IP and click save, no errors at all.

If I then flick off that tab and back to it, it has reverted to dynamic again.

The VM is shutdown and newly created yesterday

I know I can do it via powershell but just trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or its the UI being crappy.

Just as a caveat, I'm pretty familiar with server admin etc but reasonably new with Azure and what not, so be gentle :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested on one of my VM and I think that you need to remove the association between the network interface and the IP address before making it static.

So, first, go in the Network Interface of your VM. Go into the IP Addresses settings and disable the Public IP address.

Then go in your Public IP address settings, click Configuration, choose to make it static. Wait for the confirmation.

Then go back in the Network Interface settings of your VM and re associate the IP address.

It should work now.

Comment: hmm, I have an error now trying to make the IP dynamic... Can you check if you have some error in the javascript console of your browser when you save the modifications on the network interface ? I already have openned an issue for this point, hope it will be solved soon. I think you'll have to use PowerShell until the issue is solved...

Comment: It works now, a fix has been deployed on the portal :) be sure to refresh your browser (ctrl+F5)

Comment: Thanks for the input, seems the fix to the portal sorted this out